# How to make my method add constructed optional arguments into my arrayList

Tags: java, for-loop

I'm trying to make make a method that adds an Account to my ArrayList if it doesn't exist already. Like this.

```
    public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
        for (Account acc : accountList) {
            if (!acc.equals(account))
                accountList.add(acc);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

But I want another overriding addAccount method to be constructed with the optional parameters like this

```
public Account(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance)
```

This is what I currently have, but is not working

```
    public boolean addAccount(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance) {
       for (Account acc : accountList) {
            if (!acc.getAccountName().equals(accountName))
               accountList.add((acc(accountName,accountNumber,accountBalance)));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Your first implementation seems to have a logic flaw. If `accountList` is not empty, the method will always return `true` whether `account` was found or not. Further, you're adding `acc` (not `account`), thus creating a duplicate in the very code that is trying to avoid duplicates. And lastly... Maybe you want to use a `Set` rather than a `List`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, you have a constructor like `Account(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance)` you can try this:

```
public boolean addAccount(String accountName, int accountNumber, double accountBalance) {
    boolean found=false;
    for (Account acc : accountList)
        if (acc.getAccountName().equals(accountName))
           found=true; 
    if(!found){
        accountList.add(new Account(accountName,accountNumber,accountBalance));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this, no need for for loop

```
public boolean addAccount(Account account) {
    if(!accountList.contains(account)) {
        accountList.add(account);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Add equals method in your model class `Account.java`

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Account other = (Account) obj;
    if (accountNumber != other.accountNumber)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```